# How to translate this inner join T-SQL into LINQ-to-Entities?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I have a snippet of Stored Procedure:

```js
...
SELECT B.BinID, AverageCost, SUM(Qty) AS Qty
FROM #CurrentReturn R INNER JOIN Bins B ON R.BinCode = B.BinCode AND B.StoreroomID = @StoreroomID
...
```

`@StorerroomID` is one of the SP parameters.

Now I am trying to translate it into LINQ to Entities,

```js
var AverageCostList = from r in CurrentReturn
                      join b in BinQuery on new {r.BinCode, b.StoreroomID} equals new {b.BinCode, storeroomID}
```

It does not work, as the type on the L.H.S. of `equals` cannot contains fields in b.

So is there any way to translate such an inner join SQL into LINQ?

Comment: Show us the code of CurrentReturn and BinQuery. I think you are not using Linq TO Entities but Linq To Object because I don't see the DbContext on your query

Comment: Anyway the case of `storeroomID` into the two anonyme types : `storeroomID` != `StoreroomID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would put the `B.StoreroomID = @StoreroomID` comparison into ther where clause

```
from r in CurrentReturn
join b in BinQuery 
on r.BinCode equals b.BinCode
where b.StoreroomID == storeroomID
```

Comment: just curious, is it producing same result set, and is it more effective? As I myself always prevent using join if I can use where, do not know why the stored procedure wrote it that way though...

Comment: should be same effective - that's the same like `SELECT * FROM CurrentReturn r, BinQuery b WHERE b.BinCode  = r.BinCode AND b.StoreroomID =  @StoreroomID `;